# How to provision a test user in kamailio?

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server, kamailio

I have just (for the first time) compiled and installed kamailio, following [this](http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/) guide. For configuration, I am following the documentation [here](http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/)

I am trying to test a new SIP user. I have created it with:

```
» kamctl add test testpasswd
```

The user is there:

```
» kamctl db show subscriber
|----+----------+--------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------|
| id | username | domain             | password   | email_address | ha1                              | ha1b                             | rpid |
|----+----------+--------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------|
|  5 | test     | tethys.wavilon.net | testpasswd |               | 5cf40781f33c6f43a26244046564b67e | eb898de815bc16092e4c2e8c04bfe188 | NULL |
|----+----------+--------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------|
```

I try to connect with my sip client, and the registration times out (`Request Timeout (408)`). I have tried to verify what is going on by doing:

```
» kamailio -l <my-ip> -E -ddddd -D 1
```

And I see lots of messages, one of them interesting:

```
0(15818) DEBUG: auth [api.c:86]: pre_auth(): auth:pre_auth: Credentials with realm '<my-ip>' not found
```

But I do not know how to solve this problem. How can I verify what credentials associated to realm `<my-ip>` are configured? What is a "realm"? I do not find any beginners guide for `kamailio`. Is there a simple how-to on how to setup a simple `kamailio` configuration?

Answer (score 4):

The log message you pasted in the question is for debug purposes (hence DEBUG level) and it could be printed for first SIP requests that come with no credentioals (e.g., first REGISTER) -- in such case it is all ok. Those requests are challenged for authentication with 401 replies, then they are resent by phone with credentials in Autorization header.

If for those requests with credentials you don't get the same realm as used in challenge function parameters (e.g., www_challenge(), auth_challenge()...), then the SIP phone might be misconfigured. Typically the realm is the same as SIP domain in order to ensure it is unique, but that is not a must. With default kamailio configuration, the realm is the From header URI domain.

However, you say you get 408 timeout for registration, then the issues might be something else. When the credentials matching the realm are not found, then 401reply is sent back, not 408.

The reason for timeout could be that the REGISTER didn't get to kamailio or kamailio tries to send it somewhere else. You should look at the SIP traffic on the kamailio server to see what happens. You can use ngrep for that purpose, like:

```
ngrep -d any -qt -W byline . port 5060
```

Watch to see if the REGISTER comes to kamailio server and if it is attempted to be sent to another IP.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I that add the alias record in kamailio.cfg and it works well.

```
alias="tethys.wavilon.net"
```

Answer (score -1):

Kamailio is a proxy. It is not simple, so if you want something simple, try [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) instead. Kamailio configuration **requires** knowledge of SIP.

For this problem: you set the realm somewhere (in config file or in database) but are not using it for registration. Possible solutions would be to:

1. Remove the realm or set it to the correct domain name (and use it!). In the default config, that means disabling domains.
2. Use `tethys.wavilon.net` as you described in the subscriber table.

For more info, go to the Kamailio site and read [this document](http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/4.1.x/modules/auth_db.html).

Comment: I am *moving* from asterisk to kamailio (for the SIP part), because I am having trouble with NAT in asterisk. I understand kamailio is quite complex and feature rich, but a simple "hello-world" setup would be very helpful. I guess everybody wants to connect to kamailio with a sip client in the first try, so I was hoping there is an example on how to set this up for a test user.

Comment: Nat on kamailio is much more complex. Default config offer simple setup, but as u say u have problem with it. Sure, there are ALOT of examples. No idea why you can't implement any. There are alot of tutorials including simple one at project start page: http://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/start. Note, correct nat is not simple.